# JSON2 vs. jquery-json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-plugins

This is probably a simple question, which I can't seem to find a solid answer to.

Why would one choose JSON2 over jquery-json plugin (http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/)?  Given that a web application is using jQuery to begin with.

Everyone's writing about how great it is that JSON2 falls back on the native implementation; well, so does jquery-json.  I welcome links to blogs, articles and examples.  However, I'm looking for a strong solid answer on which one is better to use and why.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

An important difference between the two is that JSON2's api is exactly the same as the native api whereas jquery-json is a jquery plugin (which is slightly different than falling back on the native implementation).

I would say your answer depends on which api you want to use since you'll get the same results with either implementation (you should at least).

As a thought experiment, let's imagine that every browser had a native JSON api implementation.  Would you still use jquery-json?

If so, then use the jquery plug-in.

If not, then why would you tie your code to the jquery-json api when the native api is already well-known (even if its not globally implemented)?

If it means anything to you, John Resig (the creator of jQuery) [has said](http://ejohn.org/blog/ecmascript-5-strict-mode-json-and-more/) "In the meantime PLEASE start migrating your JSON-using applications over to Crockford's json2.js"

Comment: Good thought. If all browsers had native JSON api, I would NOT use any plugin. Let me take a look at that link to John's blog.

Comment: I think the answer takes several readings until one gets that json2.js implements the native API and that jquery-json does not.

Answer (score 16):

Author of jquery-json here.  It really doesn't matter much.  I made jquery-json a long time ago when there were no good options, and keep it there because a lot of people like it.

They are both a handful of functions that do just about the same thing.

Answer (score 2):

Most modern browsers have [native JSON](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/Using_JSON_in_Firefox) build in, jQuery defaults to those functions when using e.g. [$.getJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) or [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.parseJSON/).

So if you are using jQuery, you don't need any plugin/library for JSON.

Comment: Most of the time, I use $.ajax() function, so I need to serialize/deserialize somewhat manually.

Comment: You shouldn't need to deserialize your data if you set the dataType property of the configuration object you pass into `$.ajax()`

Comment: @Ken Browning - I was getting my data from an asmx service.  So it was prefixed with Microsoft's 'd'.  I had to do something like $.evalJSON(resultData.d) with jquery-json plugin.  That was sometime back, though.  I'm currently trying to evaluate some UI related questions/issues for an upcoming project. Thanks for the suggestion.