# Asmx web service how to return JSON and not XML?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asmx, javascriptserializer

My service method:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public string getDataFromTrainingMaster()
{
    List<TrainingMasterDataStruct> results = new DAL().GetDataFromTrainingMaster();
    JavaScriptSerializer js = new JavaScriptSerializer();                    
    return js.Serialize(results).ToString(); 
}
```

My .net web service returns JSON wrapped in XML as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<string xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">   [{"Training_Code":"1234 ","Training_Duration":"2hrs ","Training_Startdate":"2/14/2013 3:00:00 PM","Training_Enddate":"2/14/2013 5:00:00 PM","Trainer_ID":1,"Training_Location":"B-Wing Training room-4","Comments":"C# training","Keyword":"C#1234","NumberofDays":1},{"Training_Code":"4321 ","Training_Duration":"16 ","Training_Startdate":"2/17/2013 10:30:00 AM","Training_Enddate":"2/17/2013 5:30:00 PM","Trainer_ID":2,"Training_Location":"A-Wing Training Room-6","Comments":"Objective-C","Keyword":"Obj-C4321","NumberofDays":2}]
```

I need it in the following format:

```
"Training":[{"Training_Code":"1234 ","Training_Duration":"2hrs ","Training_Startdate":"2/14/2013 3:00:00 PM","Training_Enddate":"2/14/2013 5:00:00 PM","Trainer_ID":1,"Training_Location":"B-Wing Training room-4","Comments":"C# training","Keyword":"C#1234","NumberofDays":1},{"Training_Code":"4321 ","Training_Duration":"16 ","Training_Startdate":"2/17/2013 10:30:00 AM","Training_Enddate":"2/17/2013 5:30:00 PM","Trainer_ID":2,"Training_Location":"A-Wing Training Room-6","Comments":"Objective-C","Keyword":"Obj-C4321","NumberofDays":2}]</string>
```

How can I do this?

Comment: What technology have you used to create the web service? ASP.NET Web API? Static page method? WCF?

Comment: Thanks for clarifying by adding your server-side code, I see you're using `WebMethod` attribute. This is one of *many* different web service frameworks, so be sure to mention that when raising a question. Looks like the same issue discussed (and answered) here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5611134/responseformat-json-returns-xml

Answer (score 2):

There's no need to create the JSON string yourself. Return the `List<TrainingMasterDataStruct>` and let .NET serialise it for you on the fly:

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public List<TrainingMasterDataStruct> getDataFromTrainingMaster()
{
   List<TrainingMasterDataStruct> list = doStuff();
   return list;
}
```

Secondly, the non-static method signatures suggest this is an asmx file (page methods are static). By default these serialise to xml so you will need to uncomment or add the `System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService` attribute to the web service class:

```
[WebService(Namespace = "http://tempuri.org/")]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[System.Web.Script.Services.ScriptService]
public class WebService : System.Web.Services.WebService {
```

This allows it to return JSON. One issue: The JSON serialiser seems to be able to serialise more types than XML so be careful here if you want to output either/or - use Lists and arrays here rather than collections.

Thirdly and **very importantly**, the CLIENT must indicate to the server that it desires a JSON response.

To test and verify this third point, I suggest you follow the above steps and then make a call to the web service from a test web page using jQuery and monitor the traffic in [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com/). Something like:

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "WebService.asmx/getDataFromTrainingMaster",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: "",
        success: function (msg) { }
    });
```

This is what a JSON request/response looks like - pay particular attention to the POST, Accept and Content-Type headers:

```
POST http://scrubbed/GetVehicles HTTP/1.1
x-requested-with: XMLHttpRequest
Accept-Language: en-gb
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 8.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/4.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E; InfoPath.2)
Host: scrubbed
Content-Length: 0
Connection: Keep-Alive
Pragma: no-cache

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private, max-age=0
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
Date: Mon, 04 Oct 2010 10:49:12 GMT
Content-Length: 1417

{"d":{"Data":[{"Key":1,"Value":[{"VehicleId":15036,"VehicleAlias":"Whatever","Expiry":"\/Date(1915983035043)\/","Expired":false},{"VehicleId":
```

Answer (score 0):

Try changing your return type to `List<TrainingMasterDataStruct>` and returning "`results`". You don't need to serialize the string yourself, ASP.NET with the WebMethod attribute will take care of that for you.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
var data = [{"Training_Code":"1234 ","Training_Duration":"2hrs ","Training_Startdate":"2/14/2013 3:00:00 PM","Training_Enddate":"2/14/2013 5:00:00 PM","Trainer_ID":1,"Training_Location":"B-Wing Training room-4","Comments":"C# training","Keyword":"C#1234","NumberofDays":1},{"Training_Code":"4321 ","Training_Duration":"16 ","Training_Startdate":"2/17/2013 10:30:00 AM","Training_Enddate":"2/17/2013 5:30:00 PM","Trainer_ID":2,"Training_Location":"A-Wing Training Room-6","Comments":"Objective-C","Keyword":"Obj-C4321","NumberofDays":2}]

var result = JSON.stringify({ Training: data })
```

`result` will give you the desired output.

Comment: from which namespace "JSON" belogs.Now getting error, "JSON" is not in current context.

Comment: Actually json.stringify is a javascript function so you can try using ajax to call your web service on client side and use this.May be this will work.

Comment: JSON.stringify is not built in to all browsers. Use json2.js. https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar error. One method returns the response in correct json format but another method returns xml in the same asmx.

Here the two methods:

Response in JSON format:

```
[WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string loginOne(string param1, string param2){
          result = new JObject();
          ...
          ...
          return result.ToString();
    }
```

Response in XML format:

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string getCompaniesOne()
    {
        ...
        ...
        return result.ToString();
    }
```

How I solved?

Adding a dummy parameter to the wrong response method.

```
 [WebMethod]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string getCompaniesOne(string dummy)
    {
       ...
       ...
       return result.ToString();
    }
```

I Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

The problem can be circumvented in the following way.

This asmx service will return the JSON value: {"d":"Hello World"}

```
<%@ WebService Language="C#" CodeBehind="Data.asmx.cs" Class="WebServiceData" %>

using System.Web;
using System.Web.Services;
using System.Web.Script.Services;

[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class WebServiceData : WebService
{
    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public void Get()
    {
        object ret = new {
            d = "Hello World"
        };

        string retjson = new System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(ret);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();
        HttpContext.Current.Response.ContentType = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
        HttpContext.Current.Response.AddHeader("content-length", retjson.Length.ToString());
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(retjson);
        HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
    }
}
```