# AJAX request not working with ASP.Net C# - 500 server error

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, javascriptserializer, pagemethods

I tried this page method code in my ASPX page (ShowUsers.aspx), but the function gave me a `500` server error and does not go in to the `success` handler.

```
[WebMethod]
[ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
public static string GetInfo(string email)
{
    JavaScriptSerializer jss = new JavaScriptSerializer();
    User user = UserService.GetUser(email);
    return jss.Serialize(user);
}
```

And the JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#l").click(function() {
    $("#modalUpdate").fadeIn(1000);
    var url = "ShowUsers.aspx/GetInfo";
    var email = "davidizhakinew@gmail.com";

    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      type: "POST",
      data: "{ email : " + email + " }",
      dataType: "JSON",
      contentType: "application/JSON; charset=utf-8",
      success: function(msg) {
        alert("success");
        var data = JSON.parse(msg.d);
        // do stuff (trimmed)
      },
      error: function(msg, xhr) {
        alert(msg + ", " + xhr.responseText);
      }
    });
  });
});
```

Can someone help me please?

Comment: F12->Network -> Response will show you the exception. It will be a null exception since you are reading querystring parameters (string email) but not providing them in the Url. To bind Post data to function parameters, but [FromForm] before string email.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON is invalid as you have not enclosed the email-address string [inside quotes](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_strings.asp) in JavaScript.

Programmatic proof that this will cause a server-side exception:

```
void Main()
{
    string email = "davidizhakinew@gmail.com";
    var postback = new Postback { email = email };

    Console.WriteLine(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Postback>("{ email : '" + email + "' }")); // email string escaped, ok
    Console.WriteLine(new JavaScriptSerializer().Deserialize<Postback>("{ email : " + email + " }")); // YOUR INPUT, exception Invalid JSON primitive
}

public class Postback
{
    public string email { get; set; }
}
```

A server-side exception manifests itself as an Internal Server Error, code `500`. You should be able to see the exception details in the Windows event viewer.

So in JavaScript just wrap the email address inside quotes:

```
data: "{ email : '" + email + "' }",
```

Also note that all you need for your web method body is

```
public static User GetInfo(string email) {
   return UserService.GetUser(email);
}
```

i.e. [you do NOT need to spin up a serializer yourself](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16335022/397817). The Framework selects and spins up the necessary serializer (JSON or XML) based on the request headers.

Answer (score 1):

AJAX call is returning status code `500`. This is definitely an error on C# code, not JavaScript.
Status code `500` means *Internal Server Error*. ASP.NET applications throw that code when any exception occurs. Take a look in your logs / console output on C# side.

I suppose that the problem is in the method name. If not otherwise specified, due to ASP.NET naming conventions, your `GetInfo` is callable with `GET` method. You are calling this endpoint with `POST`, try to change that to `GET`.

Also, try other URL combinations, like:

- `ShowUsers/GetInfo`
- `ShowUsers.aspx/Info`
- `ShowUsers/Info`

Answer (score 0):

Create a new page and receive data from that page instead of receiving from the same page in asp.net
It is wrong to call

```
`"ShowUsers.aspx/GetInfo";`
```

try this with new page

```
`showUsersAjax.aspx'`
```

and make sure that your url should be like

```
var url = "http://www.doamin.com/ShowUsers.aspx/GetInfo";
```

try this

```
var url = "http://www.doamin.com/ShowUsers/GetInfo";
```

Assuming that ShowUsers is controller and GetInfo is the action
additionally, add POST signature in your API.

Comment: A relative URL is absolutely fine, and in many cases more logical. It's not 'wrong' to use them at all. Though the OP should probably base them from the root of the domain.

Comment: my friend did like this and it is working for him well i near to him right now ...

Comment: @DavidIzhaki you cannot call method in aspx, however it can be done in mvc.

Comment: @AayQue my friend near to me have a project like me and it is working for him right now...

Comment: No, it's called a page method and it is perfectly logical and legal in classic ASP.NET.