# Invalid JSON primitive: lookupID.","StackTrace":"

Tags: c#, json, ajax, serialization, webmethod

I can't figure out why I am getting this error.  When I put quotes around the variables, it literally sends the text instead of the variable.

> {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: lookupID.","StackTrace":"   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeDictionary(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)\r\n   at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}

My ajax function:

```
function GetVisitDates(lookupID, IsMiscellaneous) {
    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "Home.aspx/GetVisitDates",
    data: "{ 'LookupID': lookupID, 'isMiscellaneous': IsMiscellaneous }",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    async: true,
...
```

The Method it Calls:

```
[WebMethod]
    public static string GetVisitDates(int LookupID, bool isMiscellaneous)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to `JSON.stringify()` the data first before you send it - unfortunately `.aspx` WebMethods are very picky about how they bind parameters :)

If you use your Browser's F12 tools to look at the actual `POST` request, you will see that your code currently sends the payload like this:

```
LookupID=20&isMiscellaneous=true
```

However in order for this to correctly bind, it needs to be actual JSON, like this:

```
{LookupID: 20, isMiscellaneous: true}
```

And that's where `JSON.stringify` comes in.

Here is the code I used to replicate and confirm that this solves the problem:

in Home.aspx.cs:

```
public partial class Home : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    [WebMethod]
    public static string GetVisitDates(int LookupID, bool isMiscellaneous)
    {
        return string.Format("{0}-{1}", LookupID, isMiscellaneous);
    }
}
```

On the client side (in my case just a script in Home.aspx):

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
            GetVisitDates(20, true);
        });

        function GetVisitDates(lookupID, isMiscellaneous) {
            var data = {
                "LookupID": lookupID,
                "isMiscellaneous": isMiscellaneous
            };

           data = JSON.stringify(data);

            $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "Home.aspx/GetVisitDates",
                    data: data,
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    async: true,
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr);
                    }
                }
            );
        }
```

Finally, [here](http://encosia.com/using-jquery-to-directly-call-aspnet-ajax-page-methods/) is a reference that is pretty good for using ajax with Webforms...hope that helps!

Comment: This works!  Thank you!  I didn't use this line in the asp ` [ScriptMethod()]`  It seems to work without it.  Now I am just getting a jquery error when looking at the returned value.

Comment: @Mr.Robot - oh that ScriptMethod thing was a mistake, it's not required, will remove. If you're having problems with the return data, just post another question and I'm sure you'll get a good answer :)

Comment: I figured it out on my own, I realized I wasn't using the $.each() properly.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the quotes throw it off.

I would put the JSON into its own variable first:

```
function GetVisitDates(lookupID, IsMiscellaneous) {
var data = {
   "LookupID" : lookupID,
   "isMiscellaneous" : isMiscellaneous
};

$.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "Home.aspx/GetVisitDates",
data: JSON.stringify(data),
contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
dataType: "json",
async: true,
...
```

Alternatively, this might work, not entirely sure on top of my head:

```
data: { 'LookupID': lookupID, 'isMiscellaneous': IsMiscellaneous },
```

EDIT: Steven Bryne is the correct answer. You want to add JSON.stringify().
I updated my answer as well.

Also see: [Invalid JSON primitive ERROR](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17873926/invalid-json-primitive-error)

Comment: I tried this but I still got the error....   {"Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: LookupID.","StackTrace":"  ...

Comment: Can you give this a try: data: JSON.stringify(data),