# Using JSON to Call Web Service from jQuery

Tags: c#, jquery, ajax, web-services, asmx

What a pain! I'm trying to call a web service from JavaScript but I just can't seem to find the magic sauce needed to make it work.

My code looks something like this:

**JavaScript:**

```
$.ajax({
    url: "/Services/CompanyContactServices.asmx/AddContact",
    type: 'POST',
    contentType: "application/json",
    dataType: "json",
    data: {
        companyId: 3725, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email
    },
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Success!');
    },
    error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        alert(errorThrown);
    }
});
```

**Web Service (asmx.cs):**

```
[WebService(Namespace = CompanyListServices.XmlnsNamespace)]
[WebServiceBinding(ConformsTo = WsiProfiles.BasicProfile1_1)]
[ScriptService]
public class CompanyContactServices : System.Web.Services.WebService
{
    public const string XmlnsNamespace = "mynamespace";

    [WebMethod(EnableSession = true)]
    [ScriptMethod(ResponseFormat = ResponseFormat.Json)]
    public string AddContact(int companyId, string firstName, string lastName, string email)
    {
        return new JavaScriptSerializer().Serialize(0);
    }
}
```

A breakpoint at the start of my `AddContact` method is never reached.

The `error` handler for my `ajax()` call contains the following error message in `jqXHR`:

> { Message":"Invalid JSON primitive: companyId.",
> "StackTrace":"at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializePrimitiveObject()
> at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.DeserializeInternal(Int32 depth)
> at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptObjectDeserializer.BasicDeserialize(String input, Int32 depthLimit, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
> at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize(JavaScriptSerializer serializer, String input, Type type, Int32 depthLimit)
> at System.Web.Script.Serialization.JavaScriptSerializer.Deserialize[T](String input)
> at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParamsFromPostRequest(HttpContext context, JavaScriptSerializer serializer)
> at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.GetRawParams(WebServiceMethodData methodData, HttpContext context)at System.Web.Script.Services.RestHandler.ExecuteWebServiceCall(HttpContext context, WebServiceMethodData methodData)","ExceptionType":"System.ArgumentException"}"

Chrome reports the following network data:

> Request URL:.../Services/CompanyContactServices.asmx/AddContact
>
> Request Method:POST
>
> Status Code:500 Internal Server Error

Can anyone see what I'm missing?

Comment: [Is this the same problem?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445874/messageinvalid-json-primitive-recordid)

Comment: You might want to look into the ASP.NET Web-API to have an easier time at the back-end. Of course, if you like to micromanage the json serialization and stuff in your web methods, you can stick with the older tech...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
{ companyId: 3725, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email }
```

The code above is a javascript object, not a JSON. JSON is a string representation of a javascript object. Modern browsers have `json.stringify` implemented, but if you plan to control degradation you need a polyfill like [JSON3](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/).

Example:

```
var company = {companyId: 3725, firstName: firstName, lastName: lastName, email: email};
var json = JSON.stringify(company);
```

Comment: Yes, this fixes it (given @Blazemonger's change to make JSON all upper case).

Comment: Yeh, my bad. Please mark as a answer.