# Getting 500 error when sending Ajax request

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have read every post here about it and didn't find the answer to fix it.

I have an action in this controller:

```
public class AccountController : Controller
{
    [HttpPost]
    public JsonResult CheckUsername(string i_username)
    {
        var MembershipProvider = new OtakimMembershipProvider();

        return Json(MembershipProvider.CheckUsername(i_username));
    }
}
```

This is the code in the `View`:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("CheckUsername", "Account")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: { 'i_username': 'silagy' },
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
        alert(data);
    },
    error: function () {

    }
});
```

Now I keep getting this error:

```
POST http://localhost:61035/Account/CheckUsername 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

According to posts here, I am using this to generate the URL:

```
url: '@Url.Action("CheckUsername", "Account")',
```

---

**Restitution - EDIT**

---

OK, after digging in in debug mode i found the problem.

The error was: "Invalid JSON primitive: i_username."

and based on this post
["Invalid JSON primitive" in Ajax processing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445874/invalid-json-primitive-in-ajax-processing)

i changed my code to this:

```
var data = { "i_username": "silagy" };

            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("CheckUsername", "account")',
                type: 'POST',
                data: JSON.stringify(data),
                datatype: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                error: function (xhr) {
                    alert('Error: ' + xhr.statusText);
                },
                success: function (result) {
                    alert(result);
                }
            });
```

Comment: No i didn't but why should i add static, the controller is not a static class

Comment: You're getting a 500 error, not a 404. What's the error message you're receiving?

Comment: So which one is it: 404 or 500? It's really not the same thing... Add a break point and see the action getting hit. Afterwards just debug your `OtakimMembershipProvider`.

Comment: This is the problem the action didn't hit. i have added a break point to the line "var MembershipProvider..."

Comment: Did you change your configurations? By that I mean routes, mainly. Your code looks ok. You can also check if the `Url.Action` worked, by inspecting your view or by setting a `debugger;` just before your `$.ajax` and opening the developer console in your browser.

Comment: @AndreiV No, i haven't

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should `json stringify` your data if you use contentType = application/json.

Try following code:

**Variant 1:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("CheckUsername", "Account")',
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ 'i_username': 'silagy' }),
    // ... 
});
```

Or change contentType to `application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8`. (actually this is the default option for jQuery ajax contentType so just removing application/json will solve the problem)

**Variant 2:**

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: '@Url.Action("CheckUsername", "Account")',
    contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
    data: { 'i_username': 'silagy' },
    // ... 
});
```