# Asp.net mvc 4 jquery ajax request return internal server error

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-ajax

I tried to establish ajax request to asp.net mvc controller , but it give me internal server error

```
// My Products Controller
[HttpPost]
    public ActionResult FilterCategeory(int prodID) 
    {
        var categs = new Categ() {PROD_ID=prodID }.Search();
        return Json(categs);
    }

//My ajax request 
$("#categs").empty();
    var prm = $("#prods").val();
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("FilterCategeory", "Products")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data: {prodID: prm },
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data)
        {
           alert('Success');
        },
        error: function () { alert('error');}
        });
```

Comment: Internal server error means your throwing an exception in the controller - debug your code! And whats the point of `string prodID` then `prodID.ToInt32()` - if its an `int` then make the parameter `int prodID`. And there is no point in `JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet` if its a POST

Comment: my controller returns list of products correctly , but i think the problem related to (return Json(categs);)
it didn't return json object but it returns c# JsonResult Object , thus i think that jquery couldn't resolve the returned object

Comment: Its supposed to return `object` [Refer the docs](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.jsonresult(v=vs.118).aspx)

Comment: What is `categs`? (show your models)

Comment: Normally, HTTP 500 internal server error happens if there is any problem in you configuration file.

Comment: @StephenMuecke Categ refers to Category , it's a class which contains Category fields like category_id,category_name ...etc

Comment: @AdershM i have no problems in my configuration files :(

Comment: @ZiadElnaggar,does a category happens to contains other categories (e.g. a property which is a collection of child categories) in which case you will have a circular reference exception?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ajax request throws **Invalid JSON primitive** exception. So Pass the data using **JSON.stringify(obj)**

**Ajax Request**

```
    var prm = $("#prods").val();
    var obj = { prodID: prm };
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: '@Url.Action("FilterCategeory", "Home")',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        data : JSON.stringify(obj),
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (data) {
            alert('Success');
        },
        error: function () { alert('error'); }
    });
```

[Check this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/2445874/2501044) hope it will help you.

You can check the error type in Firefox or Chrome
In firefox

Right click the browser click **Inspect Element**. Then selected the **Network** 
tab. When you click the request it will show header, cookies etc. From that choose Response. So you can found the error

[image]

In chrome
[image]

Comment: thank's Golda , it worked for me 
but how to debug ajax request and how to know the type of thrown exception ?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Check it how to know the type of thrown exception in ajax request