# Getting a JavaScript object into my controller: What am I missing here?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, json, asp.net-mvc

I'm getting a `500 (Internal Server Error)` when I try to run

```
    $.ajax({
        xhr: function() {
            var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
            return xhr;
        },
        type: 'POST',
        url: '@Url.Action("MyAction","MyController")',
        data:  fi,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json", // dataType is json format
        success: function(retJson) {
            // ...

        }
    });
```

where `fi` is a JavaScript map like `{org: "string1", cat: "string2", fileName: "string3"}`, and `myAction` is like

```
    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<JsonResult> myAction (FileInfo fi)
    {
```

where `FileInfo` is defined by

```
    public class FileInfo
    {
        public string org { get; set; }
        public string cat { get; set; }
        public string fileName { get; set; }
    }
```

Any idea what I'm missing here?

Comment: What is the 500 server error?

Comment: Whats in the stack trace of the 500 response, it should provide more detail?

Comment: The error is printed in the JavaScript console.

Comment: @EdwardSnowden, yes and what is it?

Comment: It's `500 (Internal Server Error)` That's the only information I have. EDIT: I see `i.ajaxTransport.send @ jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1:1
i.extend.ajax @ jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1:1
addFilesToDB @ FileUploadAsync:304
$.ajax.success @ FileUploadAsync:396
i.Callbacks.a @ jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1:1
i.Callbacks.h.fireWith @ jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1:1
k @ jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1:1
i.ajaxTransport.send.u @ jquery?v=FVs3ACwOLIVInrAl5sdzR2jrCDmVOWFbZMY6g6Q0ulE1`

Comment: Open `F12` go to the network tab, track the request and see what the response is. it should give you a fully detailed message

Comment: It's `[ArgumentException: Invalid JSON primitive: org.]`

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445874/invalid-json-primitive-in-ajax-processing

Comment: Remove `contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",` (or alternatively use `data: JSON.stringify(fi),`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with the way your JSON object is defined.

It should have the single quotes for the prop names like this:

```
 {'org': 'string1', 'cat': 'string2', 'fileName': 'string3'}
```