# Invalid JSON primitive when sending POST request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have the following ajax request in which I'm trying to send a JSON Object to the server:

```
function sendData(subscriptionJson) {




                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("SubscribeSecurities", "Subscription")',
                    data: "{'subscriptions': subscriptionJson}",
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log("success response: " + response.responseText);
                        alert("Hello: " + response.Name + " .\nCurrent Date and Time: " + response.DateTime);

                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        console.log("failure response: " + response.responseText);
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log("error response: " + response.responseText);
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });


            }
```

Based on the top answer in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2445874/invalid-json-primitive-in-ajax-processing) I added quotes around the "data" attribute, but I'm getting an error saying that the "subscriptionJSON" isn't being recognized. I tried testing with a sample string as is done in the post: data: `"{'foo':'foovalue', 'bar':'barvalue'}",` but when the controller gets the parameter of the subscriptionJson object it is null.

*What is the official way to send a JSON object via a POST request to an ASP .NET MVC controller?*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your issue is because you're not sending valid JSON. You need to wrap the keys in double quotes.  Also, `subscriptionJson` is a literal string in your code.  You need it to be a string variable.

```
data: '{"subscriptions": ' + subscriptionJson + '}',
```

Or, even better, just provide a plain object to jQuery and let it encode the values for you:

```
data: { subscriptions: subscriptionJson },
```

Comment: @SamAxe thanks - going blind. In fact I'll remove this answer as you beat me to it anyway

Comment: Don't remove it.  I removed mine! :)

Comment: @SamAxe lol I was commenting on yours as you deleted it. I was able to get the error "Invalid JSON Primitive" to go away, but the value is coming through as null in the controller

Comment: Naw.  I like your comment about the plain object with jQuery.  I never knew that.  Thanks for that.

Comment: @loremIpsum1771: without seeing the value of `subscriptionJson` and the Model it's attempting to being deserialized into, I'm not sure there's much we can do to help you more.

Comment: @SamAxe Yeah, I'll add the JSON to the post.

Comment: @SamAxe Actually, I'll just ask a separate question.

Comment: @SamAxe [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46308119/json-data-not-being-sent-in-ajax-postrequest?noredirect=1#comment79578150_46308119) is the new post if you're curious

Answer (score 0):

create a simple java script object just before Ajax statement. Build ajax options with data as

```
data : { parameterName : jsobject }
```

Note: (No quotes)

Make sure the controller action method has same parameterName.