# JSON data not being sent in AJAX POST request

Tags: jquery, json, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have an AJAX request that is sending a JSON object from a MVC View to a Controller using a POST request:

```
function sendData(subscriptionJson) {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: '@Url.Action("SubscribeSecurities", "Subscription")',
                    data: '{"subscriptions": ' + subscriptionJson + '}',
                    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                    dataType: "json",
                    success: function (response) {
                        console.log("success response: " + response.responseText);
                        alert("Hello: " + response.Name + " .\nCurrent Date and Time: " + response.DateTime);

                    },
                    failure: function (response) {
                        console.log("failure response: " + response.responseText);
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    },
                    error: function (response) {
                        console.log("error response: " + response.responseText);
                        alert(response.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }
```

The controller action has the following definition:

```
[HttpPost]
        public ActionResult SubscribeSecurities(string subscriptions)
        {
```

The JSON has the following format:

```
{
    "Subscriptions": {
        "Obj1": {
            "Value1": "3454234",
            "Value2": "345643564",
            "Value3": "665445",
            "Value4": "True"
        },
        "Obj2": {
            "Value1": "3454234",
            "Value2": "345643564",
            "Value3": "665445",
            "Value4": "True"
        },
        "Obj3": {
            "Value1": "3454234",
            "Value2": "345643564",
            "Value3": "665445",
            "Value4": "True"
        }
    }
}
```

**What could be causing the problem?**

## EDIT

Here are the updates that I made after creating objects to store the values returned by the JSON POST request.

**JSON**

```
var test = {

                    "Obj1": {
                        "Value1": "3454234",
                        "Value2": "345643564",
                        "Value3": "665445",
                        "Value4": "True"
                    },
                    "Obj2": {
                        "Value1": "3454234",
                        "Value2": "345643564",
                        "Value3": "665445",
                        "Value4": "True"
                    },
                    "Obj3": {
                        "Value1": "3454234",
                        "Value2": "345643564",
                        "Value3": "665445",
                        "Value4": "True"
                    }

                }
```

**Model to catch JSON**

```
   public class RootObject {
    // Give this a better name.  RootObject is a horrible name.

        public IEnumerable<SubscriptionObj> Subscriptions { get; set; }
}

public class SubscriptionObj
{
    public Int64 Value1 {get;set;}
    public Int64 Value2 {get;set;}
    public Int64 Value3 {get;set;}
    public Boolean Value4 {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: `data: { subscriptions: subscriptionJson },`

Comment: @Spectarion  the data value actually works as per [this posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46307652/invalid-json-primitive-when-sending-post-request/46307715?noredirect=1#comment79577452_46307715)

Comment: any error reported?

Comment: @Komal Actually, I missed the error, I will update the post with it

Comment: @Komal The error that I just saw had to do with something else unrelated. This problem is still there

Comment: Is subscriptionJson a string? That subscriptionJson is going to be  serialized into a complex object which != string.

Comment: can you try by making method as test string parameter and the same for the ajax data pass to check if simple parameter accepting or not

Comment: @Komal Hi I found the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46325235/how-to-parse-json-received-in-mvc-controller/46326154#46326154)

Answer (score 2):

Your controller is expecting a `string`, but you are sending it a custom object.

Either change your json to a string, or change what your controller is expecting to an object that matches what is being sent... for example:

```
public class RootObject {
    // Give this a better name.  RootObject is a horrible name.

    public Subscriptions Subscriptions {get;set;} = new Subscriptions();
}


public class Subscriptions {
    public Subscription Obj1 {get;set;} = new Subscription();
    public Subscription Obj2 {get;set;} = new Subscription();
    public Subscription Obj3 {get;set;} = new Subscription();
}


public class Subscription {
    public Int64 Value1 {get;set;}=0;
    public Int64 Value2 {get;set;}=0;
    public Int64 Value3 {get;set;}=0;
    public Boolean Value4 {get;set;}=false;
}
```

Your MVC controller will automatically deserialize the incoming json string into a real object.  If the deserialized object is NOT a string, it will not pass along the incoming json to your Action's string parameter.

Comment: Ok, so do I need to create objects to represent the JSON object hierarchy or is there a data type in C# that can store JSON?

Comment: I just created those objects (with different names) but it still doesn't seem to be working. I added some attributes with default values to the Subscription object. Would that have caused an issue?

Comment: I can't see what you've done, so I can't tell you where you may have gone wrong.  Did you change the Action's method signature to accept your new type?

Comment: There is not a Json data type.  Wouldn't it be cool if there was.

Comment: I took out the `= new Subscriptions()` parts of the statements because they were causing intellisense errors

Comment: Ok, so what I just did was directly copy your classes and added them as models. I'm getting the data to come through now. The issue is, the classes have hard coded attributes. How would I structure the classes if I have a dynamic amount of subscription objects?

Comment: Change `Subscriptions` to be an Array `Subscriiption[]` or `IEnumerable<Subscription>`, and change your json to be an array of Subscription objects.

Comment: It doesn't seem to be working. I just updated the post with the code I used.