# how to ignore comma when returning json mvc

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, autocomplete, split

I'm returning JSON from my controller to my view in order to populate a jquery autocomplete textbox in MVC. The problem is, some of my data contains commas, and therefore is split by the autocomplete helper.

Heres my code.

Controller:

```
    public ActionResult GetData()
    {
        var data = repository.GetData();

        return Json(data);
    }
```

View (script):

```
    $.post("../MyController/GetData",

        function(data) {
        var evalData = eval(data) + ""; //formats the text

        $("#Data").autocomplete(evalData.split(","),
        {
            max: 500,
            matchContains: true
        });
    });
```

As you can see, I am using the jquery .split helper to split the returned Json. Should I be using regex or should I go with a completely different approach?

Comment: if evalData looks like "bla bla ", "bla bla bla" ... you can split by '", "' instead of ','

Comment: How many items are you returning with GetData?  With it not accepting any parameters it will send all the data and jquery is left to do the filtering.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you're using the [Autocomplete](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Autocomplete) built into [jQuery UI 1.8](http://jqueryui.com/).  If you are, you have a couple of different options.

1. Based on one of the samples that's available in documentation, you can just give it a string specifying the URL of your service and not have to worry about parsing the return yourself.  So something along the lines of:

   ```
   $("#Data").autocomplete({
       source: "../MyController/GetData"
   });
   ```

   Your action will most likely need to respond to get requests as well as post though and your data may need to be in the form of  `[{ label: "something", value: "1" }, ... ]`
   Which you could do by shaping your data using a [Linq](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx) query before sending it out.

   ```
   var data = from d in repository.GetData()
              select new
              {
                  label = d.[whatever you want the label to be]
                  value = d.[whatever you want the value to be]
              };
   return Json(data);
   ```
2. You can combine your current implementation with parts of the example above to and get something like this:

   ```
   $.post("../MyController/GetData",
       function(data) {
           $("#Data").autocomplete({
               source: JSON.parse(data),
               max: 500,
               matchContains: true
           });
       });
   ```

   This assumes that **data** is in the form of `[{ label: "something", value: "1" }, ... ]` (see 1 for how to shape it using Linq).  The JSON parser will take care of commas in quotes problem for you.
3. You can also specify a [method to call](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/#remote-jsonp) when you want to retrieve data.

   ```
   $("#Data").autocomplete({
       source: function(request, response) {
           $.ajax({
               url: "../MyController/GetData",
               dataType: "json",
               success: function(data) {
                   response( data );
               }
           })
       }
   });
   ```

   (see above about how to shape data using Linq)

A couple of comments about your current implementation.

- You should considering using the [UrlHelper](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action.aspx) instead of hard-codeing the URL in case you ever change your routes.
- Instead of [eval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_eval.asp) you should use the [JSON2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) [library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552135/difference-between-json-js-and-json2-js) to parse the return value from your action.  It is generally a little bit more [secure](http://encosia.com/2009/07/07/improving-jquery-json-performance-and-security/) and yields better performance in newer browsers that support [native JSON parsing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON#Native_JSON).

Comment: Thanks a bunch romanArmy. I didn't get the 'source: JSON.parse(data)' paramater to work. Instead, I replaced the eval.split(',') with it and it works great.

Comment: @Darcy: to get JSON.parse to work you need to include JSON2.js file on your page.  That's where the parse method comes from.  Also, once you call **eval** you no longer have to call split, the data from your action will come back as as JSON array, so passing it as an argument to **eval** will give you back an array (the split should either be a no-op or cause an error).

Answer (score 0):

Alright, after much going back and forth and several edits here is my final answer.  :)

```
    $.post("../MyController/GetData", function(data) {
        $("#Data").autocomplete({
            source: data
        })
    });
```

Also, I believe the split function is plain javascript and not jquery.