# What is json.js and json2.js for?

Tags: javascript, json, backbone.js

I'm in the process of learning [backbone](http://backbonejs.org/) and I keep seeing these libraries mentioned.

Can't one just use two simple functions on the client,

`JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

for JSON functionality?

Particularly, this tutorial [here](http://arturadib.com/hello-backbonejs/).

Comment: I believe they're for older browsers that don't have a JSON object. If the browser does implement a JSON object, they use it instead.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/json

Comment: This is discussed here too... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/552135/difference-between-json-js-and-json2-js They augment the functionality of the existing JSON parsers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some [older browsers don't have these JSON functions built in](http://caniuse.com/json) - so the JSON JavaScript library contains code that poly-fills these older browsers to work just like the newer ones.

The notable exceptions are IE 7 and below.

Comment: I'm glad I got into web after IE7.

Answer (score 1):

They're for parsing json, I use it on my music player site: [My music player site](http://zachrip.net/p)

Basically it turns them into accessible variables that you can easily use.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can, provided your environment supports them.  But some older browsers do not include the JSON global.

These libraries fill in the gaps.

See [Can I Use](http://caniuse.com/json) for explicit details.

Answer (score 0):

The `JSON` object is relatively new, and as such isn't supported by older browsers. Those files are intended to implement that functionality for cross-browser support and backwards compatibility.

From http://ajax.cdnjs.com/ajax/libs/json2/20110223/json2.js:

> This file creates a global JSON object containing two methods: stringify and parse.

Answer (score 0):

[Difference between json.js and json2.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/552135/difference-between-json-js-and-json2-js)

> I guess parseJSON is obsolete, therefore the new version (json2)
>   doesn't even use it anymore. However if your code uses parseJSON a lot
>   you could just add this piece of code somewhere to make it work again

Answer (score 0):

### It's for legacy browser support

From the [GitHub page](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js) (emphasis mine):

> json2.js: This file creates a JSON property in the global object, if there
>   isn't already one, setting its value to an object containing a stringify
>   method and a parse method. The parse method uses the eval method to do the
>   parsing, guarding it with several regular expressions to defend against
>   accidental code execution hazards. On current browsers, this file does nothing,
>   preferring the built-in JSON object. **There is no reason to use this file unless
>   fate compels you to support IE8**, which is something that no one should ever 
>   have to do again.